# Span inside div is crossed by div

Tags: css, sass

```html
<div class="message-unread-headline" id="message-unread-headline" style="display: none;">
  <span>Unread Messages</span>
</div>
```

```css
.message-unread-headline {
  color: #e91e63;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 10px -10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;

  &:before {
    background: #e91e63;
    content: '';
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  span {
    background: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: -11px;
  }
}
```

this is how it looks

[image: this is how it looks]

I would like that pink line stops as soon as reaches the Unread Message Text
I tried with z-index, but it doesn't work. Don't know the way how to prevent that overlaying

Comment: could you add a working code snippet, or post what you expect ?

Comment: I expect to be like in Slack. We have that pink line and ti goes until Unread Messages. I don't want it to be crossed. I posted how it looks

Comment: Maybe the `span` shouldn't have a transparent background?

Comment: I want it to be transparent, or at least that it looks transparent. I don't want any boxes or so

Comment: Your `&:before` has a width of 100%.

Comment: Please post a working code Snippet, that we can work with.

Comment: You should reduce your red lines width with the width of Unread message.

Comment: You are right, width in before solves everything!! Thanks

Comment: Of course z-index doesn’t change anything, as long as the background is transparent.

Comment: @Pete yeah, I noticed. Of course that is not necessary with flexbox, because then you actually have two elements _next_ to each other, but the solutions using absolute positioning have the elements overlapping. (And with a dynamic width for the inner element I don’t see a way to get the absolute positioning “right”, so likely no way without a background in _that_ case.)

Comment: @manekinekomase if you want a more robust / re-usable answer, I have one below

Answer (score 0):

That's how I achieved this:

```css
.message-unread-headline {
    margin:0;padding:0 10px;
    background:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    color: #e91e63;
}
h2{

    text-align:right;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;

}
h2:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    border-top:solid 2px #e91e63;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <span  class="message-unread-headline">Unread Messages</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: Kind of doesn't work on the blue  speckled background - you are relying on the text to have the same background as what's behind it

Answer (score 0):

Check if this could help you.

I have removed `width: 100%` and added `right: 0` to `:before`

And give `background: #fff;` to `span`

```css
.message-unread-headline {
  color: #e91e63;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
}
.message-unread-headline:before {
  background: #e91e63;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.message-unread-headline span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="message-unread-headline" id="message-unread-headline" >
  <span>Unread Messages</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

If your purpose is just strike over a text you can go for strike  tag in html

Comment: The poster wants the line to stop before it touches the text.